# iphone Development - analyze error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

```
NSString *temp = [self randomBallPick:temp];
```

the following error:
Pass-by-value argument in message expression is undefined

why?

```
-(NSString*) randomBallPick:(NSString*) oneFilename
{

    //create an array of filenames
    NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int c=0;c<37;c++)
    {
        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ball_%d.png", c];
        [imageArray addObject: imageName];
    }

    //pick one filename
    int numFileNames = [imageArray count];
    int chosen = arc4random() % numFileNames;
    oneFilename = [imageArray objectAtIndex: chosen];
    [imageArray release];
    return oneFilename;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for -randomBallPick: please?

Comment: How have you defined the method? I would imagine the problem is there. A bit more context for this would be good too.

Comment: post it. the randomBallPick method i define like so in the header
-(NSString*) randomBallPick:(NSString*) oneFilename;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell you're creating an array of 37 file names and then return one of them randomly.

I think the following provides the same functionality:

```
- (NSString*)randomBallPick
{
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ball_%d.png", arc4random() % 37];
}
```

If you want to keep the array around and reuse it, I'd do something like this:

```
- (NSString*)randomBallPick
{
    static NSMutableArray *imageArray;

    if (!imageArray) {
        imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int c = 0; c < 37; c++)
        {
            NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ball_%d.png", c];
            [imageArray addObject:imageName];
        }
    }

    //pick one filename
    NSUInteger numFileNames = [imageArray count];
    NSUInteger chosen = arc4random() % numFileNames;
    return [imageArray objectAtIndex:chosen];
}
```

Comment: thank you! btw i'm trying in another post to add a loop that maintain a list of not yet picked balls in this array (for unique purpose) and pick it as the return, any idea how to implement in your second function (the reuse one) ?

Comment: I added an answer to your other question. HTH.

Answer (score 2):

You're not using the string you're passing in to do anything. Seems like you needn't pass it in but should initialise it inside the method, set it, `autoRelease` and `return` it

You're defining `temp` on that line so the compiler is satistifed that `temp` exists but when it's only initialised so it's not a valid pointer yet.

Hope that makes sense. This is my educated guess at what's happening. Happy to be corrected by an objective-c guru.

Answer (score 0):

**I suspect that your method expects a pointer and you are passing data by value.**

**Make sure you have `temp` defined before the line where you pass it to your method.**

Do you define `temp` before this line? In C (not sure about objective-c) if compiler does not see definition of variable before variable is used it defaults the type of variable to `int` so it calls `randomBallPick:(int)` instead of `randomBallPick:(NSString*)`.

---

It would help if you show us the function signature of `randomBallPick:` and the definition of `temp`.

Does your method look like this: `randomBallPick:(NSString*)temp` , assuming `temp` is `NSString*` ? Is `temp` initialized properly?

Additionally, assuming you already have `temp` defined before this line, you are redefining `temp` again ...